# Nutch Selenium cannot connect to Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nutch

Am trying to crawl dynamic pages using Apache Nutch 1.15.
When i run the crawl i see the following exception

```
failed with: java.lang.RuntimeException:org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055;
```

I have tried various versions of selenium standalone server (3.14, 3.5, 3.1, 2.39) and various versions of Firefox (68, 58, 57...) but i always get this error.

I've searched and come across similar questions on SO and other sites but have yet to find a solution?

Any ideas?
Is it simply a version compatibility error between selenium and firefox?

The exception also mentions

```
Build info: version: '2.48.2'
```

But I'm not sure what this is referring to? Selenium?

**Update**

So I tried the master branch, built it successfully but during a crawl i am seeing null pointer exceptions in the hadoop.log.

So I reverted back to trying to use nutch1.15 (as others online have reported selenium working with this version) and i downloaded firefox 31.4.0 and selenium 2.48.2.

I am setting and exporting the display using Xvfb as per the instructions on https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/protocol-selenium and then starting selenium using

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar
```

in a seperate terminal window (not sure if this makes a difference). Have also tried using the same terminal and launching selenium as a background process.
I have also ensured all selenium properties are set correctly as per the link above (in both $NUTCH_HOME/conf and $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/conf)

I've also tried starting selenium using (-D flag) chomedriver but I always see the same firefox error, even when chaning the driver in the seleunium properties in nutch-site.xml (i;ve changed the URL below to test from the real one):

```
    FetcherThread 41 fetch of https://test failed with: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows:
null

    Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
    System info: host: 'ip-172-30-0-146', ip: '172.30.0.146', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-157-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_222'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Am running out of ideas now and just trying different versions of firefox/geckodriver/selenium to see if it makes a difference or even if the error will change...

**Update 2**

Using the parsechecker command provided in the comments below and on the nutch-master branch i was successfully able to parse some dynamically generated pages.

But when i try to run a crawl using the below command

```
runtime/local/bin/crawl -i -D plugin.includes='protocol-selenium|parse-tika' -D selenium.grid.binary=/usr/bin/chromedriver -D selenium.enable.headless=true -s ~/seed ~/sites/test -1
```

I get

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
 (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
      (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Checking the chromedriver version and google-chrome they match according to this [link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

I have followed the steps [here](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/protocol-selenium) but got the above firefox issues, so switching to chrome which using parsechecker works but the crawl returns an error? 
Do i need to start chrome itself as a background process?
I have also tried that but the error remains. 
I have also checked that the google chrome it is launching is the same one i am launching which it is?

Can you verify if the following steps are correct, all from the same terminal:

1. /usr/bin/Xvfb :11 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
2. export DISPLAY=:11
3. start selenium (java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar &)
4. Start chrome (/etc/alternatives/google-chrome --headless --no-sandbox &) (not sure this is needed....)
5. start crawl from nutch-master: runtime/local/bin/crawl -i -D plugin.includes='protocol-selenium|parse-tika' -D selenium.grid.binary=/usr/bin/chromedriver -D selenium.enable.headless=true -s ~/seed ~/sites/test -1

Many thanks

Comment: You may want to use the recent Nutch master instead, until 1.16 is available. The Selenium-based plugins have been recently upgraded.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianNagel I'll try that.

Comment: See https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/protocol-selenium (README.md) for a detailed description how to set everything up.

Comment: Many thanks @SebastianNagel - I followed that guide. See my update above. Feels like whatever I change the firefox version to, or the selenium version or the geckodriver version I always see the same error..I've added more details above. Many thanks

Comment: For testing you might use, e.g.:
`.../runtime/local/bin/nutch parsechecker -Dplugin.includes='protocol-selenium|parse-html' -Dselenium.grid.binary=.../selenium-installation/chromedriver -Dselenium.enable.headless=true -followRedirects -dumpText https://nutch.apache.org`

Comment: Thanks @SebastianNagel. Same error from using the nutch parsechecker command: Fetch failed with protocol status: exception(16), lastModified=0: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows:
null
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: 
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Comment: In addition to chromedriver I've tested successfully `geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz` on the current Nutch master: `.../runtime/local/bin/nutch parsechecker -Dplugin.includes='protocol-selenium|parse-tika' -Dselenium.grid.binary=.../selenium/geckodriver -Dselenium.enable.headless=true -followRedirects -dumpText https://nutch.apache.org`. It might to be useful to test in local mode first, to get closer to the reason. But I'll try to test with the Selenium server.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianNagel. Appreciate the help. So when you tested the above did you start selenium in a separate terminal ? I'll do the same but I just want to be clear on the steps....are there any parameters passed to selenium when starting it?

Comment: Many thanks @SebastianNagel - trying the parsechecker using chrome worked but the crawl now shows an error saying it cannot launch chrome - can you take a quick look at my Update 2 above and let me know if the steps i have listed above are correct? Many thanks

Comment: Many thanks @SebastianNagel - got it working in the end. Thanks for the help/tips above.

Comment: @user12345 how did you get it working in the end? i'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 2):

So I managed to get this working - crawling dynamic pages and using AWS cloudsearch as the indexer.
Many thanks to @SebastianNagel for the help in the comments.
I'm not sure all the steps/config settings below are necessary but it may help someone else coming here with similar issues.

The following versions and steps were used:

**Versions:**

- ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68
- Google Chrome 76.0.3809.100
- Selenium 2.53.0
- Nutch Master branch [github link](https://github.com/apache/nutch)

**Setup:**

cd to nutch-master root directory.

See Part 2 of the following [link](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/protocol-selenium) to setup the seleunium settings.

In conf/nutch-site.xml (i set it in both conf and runtime/local/conf) set

- selenium.driver to chrome
- selenium.grid.binary to path to chromedriver (in my case /usr/bin/chromedriver)

For the user you are running the crawl as, ensure the following nutch env settings are set

- NUTCH_HOME=/nutch-master
- NUTCH_CONF_DIR=/nutch-master/conf
- Ensure /nutch-master/src/bin is on your PATH

**Steps to Crawl**

- cd /nutch-master
- /usr/bin/Xvfb :11 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
- export DISPLAY=:11
- java -jar /selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -debug &
- runtime/local/bin/crawl -i -D selenium.enable.headless=true -s ~/seed ~/test_dir -1

After this I could see the dynamic content in AWS Cloudsearch and could also query segments in the test_dir to see the dynamic content:

```
<DIR_TO_NUTCH>/nutch-master/runtime/local/bin/nutch readseg -get /test_dir/segments/20190816092351/ "https://<URL_TO_DYNAMIC_PAGE>"
```

Comment: Thanks! Would be great if you can provide a PR to update protocol-selenium's README!